# UART on discovery cortex F3 to putty terminal

Tags: uart, discovery

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

 uint8_t a;
/* USER CODE END 2 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
/* Infinite loop */
while (1)
{

}
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, &a, 1, 1);

 while (a== 'b') {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_8);
    HAL_Delay(100);
 }

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

Used CubeMX to create project, then changed in Keil (it is a piece of that)
Code was send to Discovery F3 Cortex Board.

Transmitting worked with function HAL_UART_Transmit I can see on putty terminal the data i've wrote (similar program).

Receiving does'nt work... I m trying to send the letter by putty, but nothing happens.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you received a 'b' it will remain unchanged till another character is received. So your pin will toggle every 100 ms. To avoid this, before Delay insert a change to a, like a=0.